# Java poor performance with non-static `VarHandle`

Tags: java, performance, reflection, methodhandle, varhandle

I was investigating if replacing a `java.lang.reflect.Field.get` call with a `VarHandle` would improve performance, but instead it got slower.

From benchmarking, I can see that when the `VarHandle` is `static`, it outperforms `Field.get` (obviously) - but when it's not, it's about twice as slow.

For my use-case, it needs to generic across unknown classes - so not static - e.g. think about serialization.

Is there an alternative way to outperform `Field.get`?

Benchmark:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 200, time = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class ReflectiveFieldAccessBenchmark {
    static {
        try {
            field = ReflectiveFieldAccessBenchmark.class.getDeclaredField("count");
        } catch (final ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    private static final Field field;
    private static final VarHandle staticVarHandle = getVarHandle();
    private final VarHandle nonStaticVarHandle = getVarHandle();

    private final Number count = new AtomicInteger(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    private static VarHandle getVarHandle() {
        try {
            return MethodHandles.lookup().unreflectVarHandle(field);
        } catch (final ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Object reflection() throws Exception {
        return field.get(this);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Object staticVarHandle() throws Exception {
        return staticVarHandle.get(this);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Object nonStaticVarHandle() throws Exception {
        return nonStaticVarHandle.get(this);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Benchmark                                                                         Mode   Cnt   Score    Error   Units
ReflectiveFieldAccessBenchmark.nonStaticVarHandle                                 avgt  1000   3.485 ±  0.005   ns/op
ReflectiveFieldAccessBenchmark.reflection                                         avgt  1000   2.027 ±  0.002   ns/op
ReflectiveFieldAccessBenchmark.staticVarHandle                                    avgt  1000   0.433 ±  0.002   ns/op
```

Comment: Maybe you can cache your `VarHandle`s in a `Map` with class and field name (or maybe even the `Field` instance) as key and the `VarHandle` as value?

Comment: @ThomasKläger I tried putting it in a `static final AtomicReference<VarHandle>` but it was slower still. Making it `static` is allowing some compiler magic to happen - happy to hear of a clever way to have static-but-not-actually variables!

Comment: What kind of ecosystem is this taking place in? Perhaps you could generate classes at compile-time (e.g., via an annotation processor) or at run-time and avoid reflection (when it comes to "getting" the value of a field). Doing this would probably make your project much more complex, however, and I can't promise an acceptable performance improvement.

Comment: What happens if you use an `@State` object for storing the `VarHandle` with an `@Setup` method for creating it? You can inject it using a parameter to the `@Benchmark`. I think that JMH might (not) reuse the instance of your benchmark class.

Comment: @Slaw if you take a serialization library use case, even at compile time the objects it could interact with aren't known.

Comment: @dan1st Not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but I'm seeing the same pattern as the OP with this code: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3603650

Comment: @Jack Yes, the classes you generate won't be known at compile time. But it goes from having to use reflection for every object you want to serialize to only having to use reflection once when instantiating the compile-time generated class and then not using reflection from then on.

Comment: @Jack I think I misunderstood what you meant by "the objects it could interact with aren't known". Generating classes at compile-time would obviously require cooperation with the developers writing the classes to be used with your serialization library.

Comment: Reflection based serialization is nothing worth optimizing. The alternative is not to use Reflection based serialization. The benefit will be stability and security, but well, also performance, as far as performance matters for an I/O operation…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an alternative way to outperform Field.get?

The [Lmbda](https://github.com/LanternPowered/Lmbda) library

```
ToIntFunction<ReflectiveFieldAccessBenchmark> lambdaFactory = LambdaFactory.create(new LambdaType<ToIntFunction<ReflectiveFieldAccessBenchmark>>() {
        }, MethodHandles.lookup().unreflectGetter(field));

lambdaFactoryBoxed.apply(this);
```

| Implementation | ns/op |
| --- | --- |
| Direct | 0.32 |
| Reflection | 1.92 |
| Lmbda | 0.68 |